# Can we connect to oracle database using python without cx_Oracle in Linux

Tags: linux, python, oracle

Can we connect to oracle database using python in linux without "cx_Oracle" library. We have a restriction of installing "Oracle Instant client which is mandatory required for cx_oracle library" .

We are getting below error while trying to connect to oracle database using "cx_Oracle"

```
Error: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle 
Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such 
file or directory"
```

Please suggest if there is any way to connect to oracle without "cx_oracle" and without installing Instant client

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you've tried. In particular, please explain why the instructions on the [referenced page](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux) in the error message didn't help you. Thanks.

Comment: @roaima. I have added all the details.  We have installed a library "cx_Oracle" in linux server to access the oracle database using python,  but it was throwing this error while i am executing the python script.

Comment: If that's literally all you've done then you need to do what the referenced instructions tell you to do.

Comment: @roaima. I edited the question..

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304473/python3-cx-oracle-oracle-client-library-cannot-be-loaded-libclntsh-so-on-linu

Comment: Have also found this tread to use jdbc instead of cx_Oracle
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789704/python-oracle-db-connect-without-oracle-client

Answer (score 1):

You've asked

> if there is any way to connect to oracle without "cx_oracle" and without installing Instant client

The [documentation referenced from the error message](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux) clearly states

> ODPI-C requires Oracle Client libraries, which are found in Oracle Instant Client, or an Oracle Database installation, or in a full Oracle Client installation.

If you haven't got one of these three configuration options you will not have `libclntsh.so`, which in turns means you will not be able to connect to an Oracle Database programmatically.

As suggested in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/536392/can-we-connect-to-oracle-database-using-python-without-cx-oracle-in-linux?noredirect=1#comment994453_536392) you may get some help from a StackOverflow question/answer, [Python3 cx-Oracle Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: “libclntsh.so” on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53304473/2344631), although this does presuppose that you have actually installed one of the three entities you appear not to want to install.

Comment: roaima . We have Oracle Database installation but still i am getting this issue.

Comment: Then you need to do what the page referenced by the error message tells you to do.

Comment: Yes i have followed the same steps which is not helping me. We dont have chance to install Instant client but as we have our oracle complete database is that possible without Instant client i can connect and execute the queries ?